# How to detect unexpected end of request in Express while the request body is being piped into a child process stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, child-process

I have a child process spawned in my Node.js app, the request body payload is piped directly to the child stdin.
Even though the client TCP socket is closed, no relevant events are omitted. What I tried:

`close`/`error`/`end` on `req`, `req.socket` and `child.sdtdin`; `disconnect` and `error` on the child. None of them are fired when I close the browser tab sending the request.

I'm looking for your hints.

Comment: Show us some code to get the proper help.

Comment: I started working on a minimal example and realized the problem was connected to application stack somehow (I've Nginx and a business logic layer in front of this webapp)

Comment: So, thanks, it was user error... I'm closing the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my fault, sorry.

The events are called in this particual order:

`[2017-02-19 19:10:43] [LOG]   req socket event error { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
[2017-02-19 19:10:43] [LOG]   req event close undefined
[2017-02-19 19:10:43] [LOG]   req socket event close true`